# Why are some Buttons not working in CDFPlayer?

Tags: cdf-format, button, dialog-window

I have two `Buttons` within a single panel. My problem is that after deploying that panel, the second `Button` is not working in the *CDFPlayer*. But it works in `Notebook`. Why is it not working in the *CDFPlayer*?

```
Panel[Row[{
  Button["Speak", Speak["HI"]], 
  Button["Speak2", (CreateDialog[
  Button["Ok", Speak["infratab"], Method -> "Queued"]];), 
    Method -> "Queued"]
}]]
```

Comment: Perhaps `CreateDialog` is not allowed in the Free CDF Player?

Comment: @Ajasja Then does it work in `Player Pro`?

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the [Create a Computable Document Format file HowTo](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html) (section "Interactivity in .cdf Files"):

> Dialog windows are not supported

Other links:

http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/

http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html

Comment: In the last link there is `Launch dialogs` statement. It is about Dialog, not DialogWindows, I was assured by the support the wording will be improved, but as you can see it isn't.