# How can one emulate the effect of CreateDialog for use in Free-CDF?

Tags: cdf-format

`CreateDialog` is one of the features that is [not available to Free CDF users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8329/why-are-some-buttons-not-working-in-cdfplayer).  Is it possible to create the behavior  of the test code below in a way that can be used in a CDF?

```
test = Column[{Button["Input the function", 
    CreateDialog[{"Input the function", InputField[Dynamic[f1]], 
      DefaultButton[DialogReturn[f = f1]], CancelButton[]}]],
   Dynamic@
    PopupWindow["Plot", 
     Plot[f, {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[f]]]}]
```

*Note: edited at the request of the author.  Original text can be found in the question history.*

Comment: Dialogs are disabled in FreePlayer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are some Buttons not working in CDFPlayer?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8329/why-are-some-buttons-not-working-in-cdfplayer)

Comment: @kuba, what is the solution for this then? do you have any other way to do this? thanks

Comment: Nothing general. You could try to make your app to be one layer of the Overlay while what you want to be displayed would be another one.

Comment: @Kuba I not sure I understand what you mean. Can you direct me to any example that can do what you have said. Thanks

Comment: I'm nor aware of any except some confidential I've made. The point is that instead of `CreateDialog` you just change the visible layer of `Overlay` and display something that would normally be in dialog.

Comment: Based on the conversation in the comments, this post should really be labeled "How to emulate a CreateDialog feature that works in the Free CDF player"; this change would result in a valid and valuable question that's not a duplicate in my opinion.

Comment: @bobthechemist, please feel free to change the question.

Comment: Another problem is that FreeCDF only supports Numeric InputFields so you need to adjust your example for that.